# Problem updating reac-apollo dependecies to apollo 3

Tags: apollo, react-apollo

In my project which uses Apollo 2, I import `react-apollo` dependencies like this:
`import { QueryProps } from "react-apollo"`.

Now In Apollo 3, I can't found `QueryProps` in `@apollo/client`, I have seen in the [documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/static-typing/#using-the-name-property) of apollo with typescript, that `QueryProps` its imported like this `import { NamedProps, QueryProps } from`@apollo/react-hoc`, If I install`@apollo/react-hoc`I try to import it my IDE thrown`TS2305: Module '"../../../node_modules/@apollo/react-hoc"' has no exported member 'QueryProps'.`.

So how do i import `QueryProps` dependency into apollo 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the types separately without using QueryProps.
For example:

```
import { DocumentNode, OperationVariables, WatchQueryFetchPolicy } from '@apollo/client'
```

before:

```
type Props = {
   ...
   query: QueryProps
}
```

after:

```
type Props = {
   ...
   query: {
     query: DocumentNode
     fetchPolicy: WatchQueryFetchPolicy | undefined
     variables: OperationVariables | undefined
   }
}
```